# Characterizing trend of time series in R

Tags: r, time-series, regression

I have a fairly basic statistics application question. Lets say I have a set of four fold-change values, representing the abundance of a factor as it passes through four consecutive time points:

```
x<-c(1.0, 1.2, 15.3, 0.2)
```

And I want to define its "trend" ie, a single-number representation of how it acts during the entirety of the time course.

In the example given, x has a general increasing trend.

I have tried using trendlines, but I get a lot of over-generalization of the trend, and my info is lost. Is there a more-informative solution to defining a "trend" of values as they pass through a time series?

Answer (score 1):

For 4 terms , maybe you can define a custom criteria like this :

```
length(sign(diff(x)) ==1)/length(x) > 0.5
TRUE
```

Note that if you compute the sum of slopes , you have a decreasing trend:

```
sum(diff(x))
[1] -0.8
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Lagged differences is an interesting suggestion. Would using mean(diff(x)) be more telling of a "trend" than sum(diff(x))?